# Laravel 5.6 - Efficiently get relation count and last value of updated_at column

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

Lets say I have `Posts` and `Comments` defined as:

Post.php

```
public function comments()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

Comment.php

```
public function post()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

I'd like to efficiently load Post with `number of comments` and the `updated_at` column of the comment which was updated last. How would I proceed?

The best I could think of is to load Post with all Comments but constrain the select on Comments to `post_id`, and `updated_at` columns. Then in the view count the loaded Comments to get the count and use `sortByDesc('updated_at')->first()` to get the date of last column:

MyController.php

```
Post::with([
  'comments' => function($q) {
    $q->select('post_id','updated_at');
  }
])->get();
```

my_view.blade.php

```
Comments count: {{ $posts->comments->count() }}
Last comment: {{ $posts->comments->sortByDesc('updated_at')->first()->updated_at }}
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently and only get the count of comments and value of latest `comments.updated_at` column?

MySQL or Eloquent solution is OK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve both with [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```php
Post::withCount([
    'comments',
    'comments as last_comment' => function($q) {
        $q->select(DB::raw('max(updated_at)'));
    }
])->get();

Comments count: {{ $post->comments_count }}
Last comment: {{ $post->last_comment }}
```

Comment: This was straightforward, thanks! As a side note, if your related model is camelCase (like MyComments instead of Comments) you'll need to snake_case it in the wiew (like my_comments).